# How to convert CURL [Send Grid] to http post in Flutter?

Tags: http, flutter, curl, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

CURL Code run fine to send an Email using sendGrid, 
I want to convert this code for Flutter Dart Application (as sendGrid does not have any API)

```
curl --request POST   --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send   --header 'Authorization: Bearer 
API_KEY'   --header 'Content-Type: application/json'  
 --data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "test@gmail.com"}]}],
"from": {"email": "test@hotmail.com"},"subject": "Hello, World!",
"content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Hello World App"}]}'
```

Please provide a full function

I tried something like this ...but it is not working

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> postRequest() async {
  var url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send';
  var body = json.encode({
    "personalizations": [
      {
        "to": [
          {"email": "test@gmail.com"}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "from": {"email": "test@hotmail.com"},
    "subject": "Hello, World!",
    "content": [
      {"type": "text/plain", "value": "sent from flutter "}
    ]
  });

  var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: {
      'Authorization':
          'Bearer API_KEY',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

    body: body,
  );

  // todo - handle non-200 status code, etc

print(json.decode(response.body))
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you  try this ?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer API_KEY',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  var data = '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "test@gmail.com"}]}], "from": {"email": "test@hotmail.com"},"subject": "Hello, World!", "content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Hello World App"}]}';

  var response = await http.post('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send', headers: headers, body: data);
  print(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode != 200) throw Exception('http.post error: statusCode= ${response.statusCode}');
  
}
```